# What to do with empty directories from Cassandra on disk?

Tags: cassandra

I have Cassandra 3.11.4 and been running a test environment for a while. I have done nodetool cleanup, clearsnapshot, repair, compact etc and what remains in the data storage directory for my keyspace contains numerous "empty" directories.

When running du from the directory:

```
0       ./a/backups
47804   ./a
0       ./b/backups
0       ./b
0       ./c/backups
0       ./c
0       ./d/backups
0       ./d
7748832 .
```

Just a portion of the data with names renamed to generic letters, but essentially there are many of these empty directories remaining. The tables referenced however have either already been dropped a long time ago i.e. longer than gc_grace_seconds but the directory links remain? These are not snapshots, as making a snapshot and clearing it with nodetool clearsnapshot works fine.

Before I manually delete each of the empty folders, which is going to be a pain as there are a lot of them; am I missing a step in maintaining my cluster which causes this or is it something that happens and would have to be handled regularly assuming many changes in my test schemas?

Snapshots get cleared and the /backups trailing kind of mean that these are incremental backups?

> https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/operations/opsBackupIncremental.html

Even if it is though, there are no methods to remove these incremental backups that I can find at least with nodetool, and at the least, the setting for incremental_backups in cassandra.yaml is False.

I believe there are answers stating it is safe to delete these "ghost" directories but it would be extremely annoying if the keyspace has many of these. Also, maybe it is just my idea of wanting clean directories, would these "ghost" directories have an impact on performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the "ghost" table directories are either from:
1) empty table - still a valid table, but no data ever inserted
2) truncated tables
3) dropped tables

In the first and second case, if you remove the directory, you could end up causing issues. If you want to validate whether the directory is in use for that table you can query:

```
select id from system_schema.tables 
where keyspac_name = 'xxxx' and
      table_name = 'yyyy';
```

That ID is the id used for the directory extension for that table. Any other occurrences of that directory for that table for that keyspace are not in use.

-Jim

Comment: tables should always have UUID appended to their names, so even if you drop table & recreate, it doesn't clash with previous version

Comment: So this is an expected behavior of cassandra in normal operation?

Comment: yes. What you're seeing is normal. You'll just want to be somewhat careful of the causes (described above) so that you don't blow away an empty directory, say, of an empty table. Not sure what happens if you do that. Haven't tried it. Maybe I'll give it a shot in the lab.

Comment: @JimWartnick Thanks. Accepted your answer.I am pretty clear which folders are no longer used. but its a pain to do the cleaning on each node of the cluster. Thanks for the explanation anyways.